# function declared with const uses the old value of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, use-state, react-functional-component

I have a React component (functional) that contains a child component modifying the state of the parent component. I am using the hook **useState** for this.

After the state change, there is a "Next" button in the parent component that executes a function referencing the updated state. The problem is this next function uses the old state from before the state was modified by the child component.

I can't use **useEffect** here as the function needs to execute on the click of the "Next" button and not immediately after the state change. I did some digging about **JavaScript closures**, but none of the answers address my specific case.

Here's the code

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

    const handleNext = () => {

        console.log(myState);      // prints 0 which is the old value
    }

    return (

        <ChildComponent modifyState = {setMyState} />

        <Button onClick={handleNext} > Next </Button>

        )
    }
    
export default ParentComponent;
```

BTW there are no errors.

Comment: Can you share your child component code too? Are you sure the state is changing?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify like this

```
<ChildComponent modifyState={(value) => setMyState(value)} />
```

Comment: I tried your method. Still the same result. Actually the modifyState function is working fine, I checked using useEffect and the value is actually getting updated. Just that the handleNext function receives the old state value somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand without your `ChildComponent` code. `setMyState` suggests that you need to update the increase the state by one when you click the `next` button, but you can't do that without also passing in the state itself.

An easier (imo) solution is to pass a handler down to the child component that is called when the next button is clicked. The handler then sets the state.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function ChildComponent({ handleUpdate }) {

  function handleClick() {
    handleUpdate();
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
}

function Example() {

    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

    function handleUpdate() {
      setMyState(myState + 1);
    }

    function handleNext() {
      console.log(myState);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
        <button onClick={handleNext}>Next </button>
      </div>
        )
    }

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy. This was actually my first approach, and it did update the state, so does the code I gave in the question; both update the state successfully. The handleNext function however still uses the old value. I'm thinking this has something to do with the fact that functions are only created in the initial render, and not updated with state change. I'm not sure though.

Comment: But in my example `handleNext` always gives the current state.

Comment: do you think it would make a difference if my child component is in a different file?

Comment: As long as you import it correctly it will work.